# How can i detect incoming voip calls (eg. whatsaap) in my app

Tags: android, voip, whatsapp

I want that whenever there is a voice call or video call over internet eg. whats-app call,my app should stop the timer which is running.Want to detect whether it is received or it is declined .Is this possible ?I have tried a lot to find this but don't understand how to achieve this.I have done this for my normal call but no luck for voip calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to listen all notifications with BroadcastReceiver and filter out call notifications.

Comment: how can i get the event of received,declined as after call is finished i have to resume the timer .

Comment: I have done something similar long time ago, cant remember bet it had something to do with reading WhatsApp notification content and id, by that you can determine whats going on and when.

Comment: will try .Thanks